# favicon.ico results in 404 error in flask app

Tags: html, browser, flask

I found a lot of entries in my logfile, which indicate that somebody tried to load /favicon.ico and similar files

```
GET - /favicon.ico
GET - /apple-touch-icon.png
GET - /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
```

I read a lot about this issue online, but I can't get rid of it. Here is what I trued. First I added the following to my head tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

However, even though I provide this information in my header, there seem to be browsers out there which don't care about it and still call /favicon.ico?
So I thought just putting the ico file at root and be done with it, but it does not seem to work? If I call

```
http://localhost:5000/static/favicon/favicon.ico
```

I get to the icon, but

```
http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico
```

Does not work (gives 404)? I cleared my cache and tried it with Chrome and Safari, but I get 404 in both cases? I am really at a loss here. If I move the image in the static folder and call

```
http://localhost:5000/static/favicon.ico
```

it works, but the root folder doesn't? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

By default, the flask will only serve files on the /static endpoint. You can add a custom view to handle the default  /favicon request.

The flask documentation has some more  information on  this subject:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/favicon/

```
import os 
from flask import send_from_directory     

@app.route('/favicon.ico') 
def favicon(): 
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
```

Comment: great that solved the issue. Do you know whether I need to create the same for the apple icos, or are those not search for if favicon.ico exists?

Comment: I think favicon.ico is the only one that fires by default. All others are optional. You can also just keep other icons in /static and use the url_for() in the template to point to the correct place, as explained in the first part of the documentation.

Comment: thnx so much , excellent fix!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a very similar problem. I do not have the necessary points to add a comment to the answer yet. So I'll do it using "Your answer". For those who need a much more specific answer on how to use url_for () here is one way to do it.

```
<!-- Adding a favicon icon to Flask app -->
<!-- SEE: https://favicon.io/favicon-converter/-->

<link rel="shortcut icon"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon"
      sizes="180x180"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='apple-touch-icon.png') }}">

<link rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="180x180"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon-32x32.png') }}">

<link rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="16x16"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon-16x16.png') }}">

<link rel="manifest"
      href="site.webmanifest">
```

To generate the necessary files use the following link: https://favicon.io/favicon-converter/ All files were copied into the /static directory.

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered favicon 404 errors in a flask app, I initially resolved the problem using `return send_from_directory()`, and supplying a favicon.ico in the 'static' folder. Eventually, I found a much more convenient way of eliminating the error, without having to supply a favicon:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

# The code below lets the Flask server respond to browser requests for a favicon
@app.route("/favicon.ico")
def favicon():
    return url_for('static', filename='data:,')
```

Now, my flask development server responds with:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Further info on the filename='data:,' argument:
[mdn web docs Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)